# Can't save the cypress screenshots in higher resolution in jenkins pipelines

Tags: docker, jenkins, automated-tests, screenshot, cypress

Is there a way to enlarge failure screenshot image ? the default is width="1050" and height="932" (I mean the output image, not viewport).
as you can see the screenshot isn't spread on the entire page
[screenshot for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Saq0.jpg)